# How to extract a string matching with preg_match

Tags: php, preg-match

I have extract to class names from the html file and each line contains the class name like

```
      </div><div id='css-11_uss_pss_sss-__i__' class='sss'> <div class="sss-top">
      </div><div id='css-42_aap-8' class='css'> <div class="sss-top">
```

I need to extract the 'uss_pss_sss' and  'aap-8' from different lines

I try this code it extracts the first condition.

```
            preg_match("/(?<=_).*?(?=-__i__)/", $buffer, $match);
```

How do i extract the second line?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 0):

You can't for two reasons:

1) `aap-8` can't be a result of your pattern since it's not followed by `-__i__` as indicated in your lookahead assertion

2) the *preg_match* function give only the first match, you must use *preg_match_all* instead

You can solve these two problems with:

```
preg_match_all("/(?<=_).*?(?=-(?:__i__)?|')/", $buffer, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: I really thank replying to my question so fast, can you provide me some pattern to get the second condition. I am not getting how to match the second condtion..